# Reliable way to get type of Clang AST node

Tags: clang, language-lawyer, clang++, llvm-clang

I am writing a tool that consumes Clang's abstract syntax tree and it seems like some of the nodes have incorrect type information. Take the following program for example,

```cpp
struct P { ... };
P& ret_ref(P& x) { return x; }
P&& ret_rref(P& x) { return x; }
```

Dumping the syntax tree with clang produces the following:

```sh
|-FunctionDecl 0x28ca4d8 <line:117:1, line:119:1> line:117:4 ret_ref 'P &(P &)'
| |-ParmVarDecl 0x28ca420 <col:12, col:15> col:15 used x 'P &'
| |-CompoundStmt 0x28ca5d8 <col:18, line:119:1>
| | `-ReturnStmt 0x28ca598 <line:118:5, col:12>
| |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x28ca578 <col:12> 'P' lvalue ParmVar 0x28ca420 'x' 'P &'
|-FunctionDecl 0x28ca800 <line:128:1, line:130:1> line:128:5 used ret_rref 'P &&(P &)'
| |-ParmVarDecl 0x28ca600 <col:14, col:17> col:17 used x 'P &'
| |-CompoundStmt 0x28ca938 <col:20, line:130:1>
| | `-ReturnStmt 0x28ca900 <line:129:5, col:30>
| |   `-CXXStaticCastExpr 0x28ca8d0 <col:12, col:30> 'P' xvalue static_cast<struct P &&> <NoOp>
| |     `-DeclRefExpr 0x28ca8a0 <col:29> 'P' lvalue ParmVar 0x28ca600 'x' 'P &'
```

Note that the `DeclRefExpr` nodes have type `P` (though the `ParmVar` that they contain is type `P&`). Similarly, note that the `CXXStaticCastExpr` also has type `P`, when it (clearly?) should have type `P&&` (it is as cast after all).

Is this something that clang is doing on purpose? Am I misunderstanding what the C++ specification says? Is this a bug in Clang?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#expr.type-1.sentence-1

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason for this? It seems very strange to forget this information.

Comment: In regards to the "why", this could be useful. https://mobile.twitter.com/matt_dz/status/1167509927105060864